# Very little code knowledge, trying to help little sister with an Arduino project

Tags: arduino

Project involves creating a number guessing game from numbers between 0-500 with an Arduino Uno board. Code seems to work fine until point of "Guess a number between 0 and 500", at which point, when a number is entered no response is given. Have not tried much as my coding knowledge is roughly nil. Project is being run in Tinkercad.

```
void setup (){
 randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
Serial.begin(9600);
for(int i=2 ; i<=11 ; i++) {
pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
 }
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Hello, whats your name?");
 while(Serial.available()==0){
}
Name=Serial.readString();
Serial.print("Hello,");
Serial.print(Name);
}

void loop(){

Serial.println("");
if (Playtime>=1){
Serial.println("Do you want to play again");
}
else{
Serial.println("Do you want to play a guessing game?");
}
while(Serial.available()==0);
Answer=Serial.readString();
if(Answer=="yes"){
 GuessCount=0;
 randNumber=random(0,500);
 Serial.println("Guess a number between 0 and 500");
 while(Serial.available()==0);
 Guess=Serial.parseInt();
 while(randNumber!=Guess){
   if(Guess>randNumber){
     GuessCount=GuessCount+1;  
     for(int i=4;i<14;i++) {
       digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
       delay(Delay1);
       digitalWrite(i,LOW);
       delay(Delay2);

    void setup (){
      randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
      Serial.begin(9600);
      for(int i=2 ; i<=11 ; i++) {
      pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
      }
       Serial.println("");
       Serial.println("Hello, whats your name?");
       while(Serial.available()==0){
        }
        Name=Serial.readString();
       Serial.print("Hello,");
        Serial.print(Name);
        }

        void loop(){

       Serial.println("");
        if (Playtime>=1){
        Serial.println("Do you want to play again");
        }
         else{
        Serial.println("Do you want to play a guessing game?");
       }
       while(Serial.available()==0);
      Answer=Serial.readString();
     if(Answer=="yes"){
     GuessCount=0;
     randNumber=random(0,500);
     Serial.println("Guess a number between 0 and 500");
     while(Serial.available()==0);
     Guess=Serial.parseInt();
     while(randNumber!=Guess){
     if(Guess>randNumber){
     GuessCount=GuessCount+1;  
     for(int i=4;i<14;i++) {
       digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
       delay(Delay1);
       digitalWrite(i,LOW);
       delay(Delay2);
```

...

Comment: Hi, the code you posted is not complete, and it is highly possible that the mistake is in the missing part…

Comment: If the guess is wrong on the first guess then you have a whole loop that locks the code up.  If the guess wasn’t right at first there’s nothing inside that while loop that asks for or gets another guess.  So it just keeps repeating that while loop but guess never changes.  It becomes an infinite loop.  Study state machines.  You don’t have to tell the whole story in one loop of the loop function.  You don’t want those whole loops.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove unused stuff from previous experiments.
2. Properly indent your code ( CTRL-T in the Arduino IDE )
3. loop() is your loop. It should not take any time. In your case there's nothing else to do while waiting for a Serial input, but soon you will want to count the response time and show that running time while waiting for a response. Blocking until a response arrives
   is rather bad.
4. Write functions to make code easier readable.
5. How do you abort that annoying game? Or come into a cheat mode? Or... ?

A little starting point:

```
// LED pins
const byte UPLed = 2; // indicates guess too low
const byte DNLed = 4; // indicates guess too high
const byte WINLed= 3;

unsigned int games = 0;
unsigned int guess = 0; // 0 : ask for new game

const unsigned int MAX = 500;
unsigned int solution; // 1 ... MAX

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(UPLed,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DNLed,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(WINLed,OUTPUT);
  greeting(); // wait for user to enter their name
  randomSeed( millis() ); // time for user response is a good random seed
}

void loop() {
  // loop duration is one guess
  if (guess == 0) { 
    startDialog();
    solution = random(1, MAX+1);
    Serial.setTimeout(10000); // 10 sec per guess, else game lost
    digitalWrite(UPLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(DNLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(WINLed, LOW);  
  } 
  guess++;
  Serial.print("Guess # "); Serial.print(guess); Serial.print(": ");
  long try = Serial.parseInt();
  if (try == 0) { lostGame(); guess = 0;}
  else if (try == solution) {wonGame(); guess = 0;}
  else if (try < solution) {
    digitalWrite(UPLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(DNLed, LOW);   
  } else { // try > solution
    digitalWrite(UPLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(DNLed, HIGH);
  }   
}

void greeting() {
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Hello, whats your name? ");
 while(Serial.available()==0){ } // block until Serial receives something
 Name=Serial.readString();
 Serial.print("Hello,");
 Serial.print(Name);
}
```

`greeting()` is just one of the convenience functions to keep loop readable. You'll have to provide `startDialog()` `lostGame()`, `wonGame()` (count games, light WINLed), too.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(Serial.available()==0){
}
Name=Serial.readString();
Serial.print("Hello,");
Serial.print(Name);
}
```

So while the Serial buffer is equal to zero, it has to read a string and print it?

It should wait until Serial.available() > 0, therefor it will trigger it's whileloop when there's an input.

The first for loop also does not have any matching initial condition (i = 2, but there's no defined i).

After reading the rest, it is (no offense, really!) a mess. Multiple void setups already indicate something is wrong.

So, as a tip, try to make short and easy pieces of code. For example start it like this:

1. Figure out how to write something in the Serial Monitor and then display it as a reponse.
2. Randomize numbers and display them
3. Upon giving a number answer, it checks if it matches the randomized number and displays the result.

Comment: You missed the { }. Jared wants the setup() function to block forever, until a response comes, then apply `readString()` to it. That's fine. Your other comment are valid. Local functions (multiple setup and loop functions) should throw a compile issue.